# bash script with grep and cut : command not found

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash, and need some simple script. It runs jar, and has to find "RESPONSE CODE:XXX". I need this response code (just XXX).  I've try this:

```
 URL=$1
echo $URL
callResult=`java -jar RESTCaller.jar $URL`
status=$?
if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
    result=`$callResult >> grep 'RESPONSE CODE' | cut -d':' -f 2`
else
    echo error
fi
```

I get `./run.sh: line 7: RESPONSE: command not found`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
result=`$callResult >> grep 'RESPONSE CODE' | cut -d':' -f 2`
```

You should be piping output to grep, not redirecting. Change it to this:

```
result=`$callResult | grep 'RESPONSE CODE' | cut -d':' -f 2`
```

Also, the syntax is a bit off, and you're better off avoiding backticks when possible. This is even better:

```
result="$(echo ${callResult} | grep 'RESPONSE CODE' | cut -d':' -f 2)"
```

Comment: The backquotes in line 3 (definition of callResult) should be straight quotes, also. Unless he meant to echo that and pipe to grep.

Comment: @theglauber Good point. I try to avoid backticks and just stick to using the usual `"$( ... )"` style, as it results in neater code.

Comment: thanks, it helped. but as I found, it gives me some xtra output, not just 200, but

200 <!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http

what's wrong with cut?

Comment: What exact output do you get when you remove the `| cut -d':' -f 2` ?

Comment: I get RESPONSE CODE:200 <!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head><meta itemprop="image" content=" ....*google site's content

Comment: This should help you get just the `200` you need. Replace your current `cut` statement with `| cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
URL=$1
echo $URL
callResult=`java -jar RESTCaller.jar $URL`
status=$?
if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
    result=$($callResult 2>&1 grep 'RESPONSE CODE' | cut -d':' -f 2)
else
    echo error
fi
```

You were piping result to some invalid file name
>> means write into file adding on..

2>&1  means redirect stderr to stdin - which is all of its output -